# $f(x, y, z) := xy + z^2$ on unit circle $B := \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1\}$

Tags: analysis, circles, maxima-minima, extreme-value-analysis

> We look at $f(x, y, z) := xy + z^2$ on unit circle $B := \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1\}$.

> A) Explain why $f$ has a minimum and maximum on $B$.

> B) Show that $f$ has no local extrema on the internal $\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1\}$.

> C) Calculate the minimum  and maximum of $f$ with the method of Lagrange on $\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$.

My ideas:

A) I don't know how to explain this properly..? I believe the sphere and the function intersect?

B) For $\nabla f (a) = 0$ is $a$ the local extremum.

We have
\begin{align}
f_x = y \\
f_y = x \\
f_z =2z.
\end{align}
So $y = 0, x = 0, z = 0$ and to see if the critic point is a maximum we need $f_xx < 0$. $f_xx = 0 \nless 0$, so it can't be a maximum and $ 0 \ngtr 0$ so it can't be a minimum either.

C) For Lagrange: $\nabla f - \lambda \nabla g =0$. Say $g(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -1$ is the restriction, then we have
\begin{align}
f_x = y \qquad g_x = 2x \\
f_y = x \qquad g_y=2y\\
f_z =2z \qquad g_z = 2z.
\end{align}
This gives:
$ y - 2x\lambda = 0, x - 2y\lambda = 0, 2z - 2z \lambda = 0$, which leads to:
\begin{align}
z = 0 \qquad x^2 = y^2, \text{so} \hspace{2mm} x = y.
\end{align}
This gives the points $(\sqrt(\frac{1}{2}),\sqrt(\frac{1}{2}), 0)$ and $(-\sqrt(\frac{1}{2}), -\sqrt(\frac{1}{2}), 0)$, which gives the same maximum as minimum??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point A, notice that $f$ is continuous and $B$  is a closed and bounded set. Therefore $f$ attains a minimum and maximum on $B$.

For C, you are missing some extrema. Notice that when $\lambda=1$, $z$ doesn't necessarily have to equal $0$. When $\lambda=1$, we still have $x=y$, so we can parameterize everything in terms of $x$ to maximize the objective. With this parameterization, our objective becomes $f(x,x,\sqrt{1-2x^2}) = x^2 + (1-2x^2) = 1-x^2$, which attains a maximum value at $x=0$, which implies $y=0$ and $z = \pm1$. So there are two more extrema, $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$. The value of the objective on these extrema is $1$, so these are maxima, whereas the objective takes on the value $1/2$ at the extrema you found, so they are minima.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed, do you think B is ok?

Comment: I didn't read it carefully the first time, but you still need to check the sign of $f_{xx}f_{yy} - (f_{xy})^2$ according to the rules here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test